# Wave motion and sound

Tags: waves, acoustics

How does amplitude depend on the medium in which wave travels? 
I came across a lot of questions that asked to find amplitude after transmission of wave in a different medium.Is there any concept relating medium and amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

You may see [Fresnel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). It shows the relationship between refractive index of the medium and amplitude.

Comment: Amplitude of waves on a string is required; not light waves. Could you please tell some other method?

Comment: Fresnel equation is a direct result of wave equation. So as long as you have wave equation of any form ( in your case, string wave), you can simply modify some term ( How can you get refractive index for a string ? ) and calculate the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the impedance $\sqrt{T\mu}$ where $T$ is the tension and $\mu$ is the mass per unit length.

[Have a look at this link.](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/transverse.pdf)